# KeyError: 'id' when may2One relationship 0d00 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I got a dropdown which is a many2One field, the issue is when creating a new record and the related field is empty I got this error:

```
Traceback:
Error: KeyError: 'id'
    at F.__getitem__ (https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/core/py_utils.js:36:19)
    at F.__getattr__ (https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/core/py_utils.js:41:21)
    at F.__getattribute__ (https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:755:29)
    at Object.py.PY_getAttr (https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:526:30)
    at Object.py.evaluate (https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1443:23)
    at Object.py.evaluate (https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1415:38)
    at Object.py.evaluate (https://xxxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1427:37)
    at Object.py.eval (https://xxxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1471:19)
    at https://xxxx-14-de431-2580878.dev.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/core/py_utils.js:156:42
    at Function._.each._.forEach
```

To elaborate more I got a Team model which is related to a sale_order_detail model, Teams are related to a SO, and you can set teams by SO and assign a team o a SOD.

the problem is when creating a new record and click on the dropdown raises the error, I think it might be because the list is empty, I've been trying to set a default empty value without any luck.

This is the field:

```
team_id = fields.Many2one('rw.team', string="Team")
```

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Check rw.team is exist or not!

Comment: it does exist, however records are empty